# R: Obtain range and frequency within interval for each column?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have ~300 rows each representing a gene, and ~30 categories as columns. My dataset looks something like this:

```
   Gene   bile_duct
1 ABCA2 -0.01319722
2 ABCA3 -0.06648552
3 ABCA5 -0.05049298
```

I am trying to 1) calculate the frequency of genes in a certain range [-3,-1] **for each column**
and 2) make an actual list of the genes in the previously mentioned range.

I'm not sure how to approach (2). For (1), my approach doesn't work, but it tries to cut the data first and then use lapply with the range function:

```
breaks = seq(-3,-1, by=2)
cut_lineage <- lapply(lineage_genes[,-1],cut,breaks)
cut_lineage <- lapply(cut_lineage,range)
```

Comment: Do you have more than 2 columns?

Comment: The values won't fall into that `breaks` specified for the data showed

Comment: Yes, I have 30 columns, and 300 rows. There are values for each column that fall into the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`. If we want to get the range of value within a single window, subset the data with  `>` or `<`, and apply `range` over it

```
lapply(lineage_genes[,-1], function(x) range(x[x >= -3 & x <=-1]))
```

If we need the "Gene" list instead of subsetting the value, subset the 'Gene'

```
lapply(lineage_genes[,-1], function(x) lineage_genes$Gene[x >= 3 & x <= -1])
```

---

In the OP's code, we are returning the groups with `cut` instead of the actual column values and it is a `factor` type.  Thus, the `range` is applied on the cut group and not on the subset of values

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution in `base R`:

#Data

```
Data2 <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ABCA2", "ABCA3", 
"ABCA5"), class = "factor"), bile_duct = c(-0.01319722, -0.06648552, 
-0.05049298), bile_duct2 = c(-0.01319722, -0.06648552, -0.05049298
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

#Function
cuts <- function(x,a,b)
{
  y<-ifelse(x>=a & x<=b,1,0)
  return(y)
}

cuts(-1.5,a = -3,b = -1)
#Apply function and create a copy of data
Data3 <- Data2
Data3[,-1] <- apply(Data2[,-1],2,cuts,a = -3,b = -1)

#Obtain sums for all columns
Sum <- colSums(Data3[,-1])
#Summary by gene
aggregate(.~Gene,data=Data3,FUN = sum,na.rm=T)

Sum
bile_duct bile_duct2 
         0          0
```

The aggregation should change with more data showing the number of values:

```
   Gene bile_duct bile_duct2
1 ABCA2         0          0
2 ABCA3         0          0
3 ABCA5         0          0
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines will store the frequencies that you want in a dataframe.

```
freqs = data.frame(col = '', n = NA)
for (i in 2:ncol(data)) {
    freqs = rbind(freqs, 
                data.frame(
                        col = names(data[i]), 
                        n = nrow(data[which(data[,i] >= -3 & data[,i] <= -1), ])
                    )
                )
}
freqs = freqs[-1,]
```

And the following lines will store the actual genes in a list object. Each item in the list object is for one of the columns.

```
lists = vector('list', ncol(data)-1)

for (i in 2:ncol(data)) {

    lists[[i]] = data[which(data[,i] >= -3 & data[,i] <= -1), 1]

}
```

If the criteria that you will use for each column will be different, these will not work.